# i was unable to find the error in path i mentioned in django

Tags: django, python-3.x

i wanted to add two numbers  .so i used request.get to get two values 
        and 
      then my code has to add the numbers and print the result on the 
    server.but 
     my terminal shows-
   `Not Found: /
   [09/Oct/2019 18:07:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 2082
   Not Found: /favicon.ico
   [09/Oct/2019 18:07:33] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2133`
in the server this is shown up

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in new12.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

add [name='add']
admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

i tried adding my appname in the INSTALLED_APP section too.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('add',views.add,name='add'),
]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'calc',
]
ROOT_URLCONF = 'new12.urls'
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                 'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                 'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def add(request):
    val1=request.GET['num1']
    val2=request.GET['num2']
    res=val1+val2
    return render(request,"result.html",{'result':res})
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form action="add">
enter ist num: <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
enter 2nd num : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

printing the result on server

result.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{{result}}
{% endblock %}
```

base.html

```
<html>
    <body bgcolor="red">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

new12/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('calc.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: Which URL you are trying to access?

Comment: calc.urls along with admin/

Comment: You're showing us two not found errors, one for the "/" url and one for the "/favicon.ico" url (don't worry much about this one, some browsers try to fetch that automatically, it doesn't really matter). The only url you defined is "/add" for which there is no error. So there's no problem. Just go to "/add" and it should work. Or is what you show not your main urls.py file? The show us that.

Comment: For the /admin url you have to add the line in your urls.py file `path('admin/', admin.site.urls),`

Comment: this is shown in the server ```Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in new12.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

add [name='add']
admin/
The empty path didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.```

Comment: Please show us **new12/urls.py**. But it just looks like you haven't defined any pattern for the empty url ("/"). "/admin" and "/add" should work.

Comment: urls.py new12                                                                                             
 ```from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include('calc.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Comment: edit your question and add urls.py as code

Comment: your problem is related to urls, you have created index.html, but you're not using it, just create view which is rendered in "/" url (root url - home page), from the "/add" page you'll submit and render result at "/" page

Answer (score 0):

your problem is related to urls, you have created index.html, but you're not using it, just create view which is rendered in "/" url (root url - home page), from the "/add" page you'll submit and render result at "/" page

Try this one:

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.result, name='result'),
    path('add', views.add, name='add'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def result(request):
    val1 = request.GET['num1']
    val2 = request.GET['num2']
    res = val1 + val2
    return render(request, "result.html", {'result':res})

def add(request):

    return render(request,"index.html")
```

index.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
  <form action="/" method="GET">
    enter ist num: <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
    enter 2nd num : <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

result.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
   {{ result }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: this is not working.a multivalued dict error is displayed for num1